# How should i get complex numbers from string?

Tags: c#, regex, complex-numbers

I found following pattern from [RegexLibrary](http://regexlib.com/UserPatterns.aspx?authorid=4a2830db-f869-4497-867b-f87f4ac5d839), and i don't know how use Match to get Re and Im values. I'm new in `Regex`. Is it a correct way to get data from a pattern?
If it's true, I need some sample code! 
This is what i think it should be:

```
public static complex Parse(string s)
{
    string pattern = @"([-+]?(\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.?\d+)([Ee][-+]?[0-2]?\d{1,2})?[r]?|[-+]?((\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.?\d+)([Ee][-+]?[0-2]?\d{1,2})?)?[i]|[-+]?(\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.?\d+)([Ee][-+]?[0-2]?\d{1,2})?[r]?[-+]((\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.?\d+)([Ee][-+]?[0-2]?\d{1,2})?)?[i])";
    Match res = Regex.Match(s, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);        

    // What should i do here? The complex number constructor is complex(double Re, double Im);

    // on error...
    return complex.Zero;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh! I know it's wrong to return Zero on error! I will handle it later! Please don't tell me about this! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they're overcomplicating the regex a bit, they are for example including support for scientific numbers and it seems that there are some errors in it.

Try this simpler regex instead.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // The pattern has been broken down for educational purposes
        string regexPattern =
            // Match any float, negative or positive, group it
            @"([-+]?\d+\.?\d*|[-+]?\d*\.?\d+)" +
            // ... possibly following that with whitespace
            @"\s*" +
            // ... followed by a plus
            @"\+" +
            // and possibly more whitespace:
            @"\s*" +
            // Match any other float, and save it
            @"([-+]?\d+\.?\d*|[-+]?\d*\.?\d+)" +
            // ... followed by 'i'
            @"i";
        Regex regex = new Regex(regexPattern);

        Console.WriteLine("Regex used: " + regex);

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write a number: ");
            string imgNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            Match match = regex.Match(imgNumber);

            double real = double.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            double img = double.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Console.WriteLine("RealPart={0};Imaginary part={1}", real, img);
        }                       
    }
}
```

Remember to try to understand every regex you use, never use them blindly. They need to be understood like any other language.

Comment: Thank you! And +1 for "understand every regex you use, never use them blindly." I will remember it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the 2 `Capture` objects from the `Match` and call `Double.Parse` on their values.

Note, by the way, that you should use a `static readonly Regex` object so that it won't need to re-parse the pattern every time you call `Parse`.  This will make your code run much faster.

Comment: Thank you! But input string could be like these values: 2 or 2i or 2+3i and... Should I separate these situations in separate patterns?

Comment: I'm too lazy to parse that monstrous regex; see if you can figure out how its groups work or write your own regex.  I  suspect that it would be easier to ditch the regex and write your own parser.

Comment: Yea! Your right! It's a very monstrous reg-expression!!! I will try my own parser if it was simpler way! :)

Answer (score 1):

This was my take in Visual Basic .NET 4:

```
 

   Private Function GenerateComplexNumberFromString(ByVal input As String) As Complex
```

```
 Dim Real As String = “(?<!([E][+-][0-9]+))([-]?\d+\.?\d*([E][+-][0-9]+)" & _
 "?(?!([i0-9.E]))|[-]?\d*\.?\d+([E][+-][0-9]+)?)(?![i0-9.E])”

 Dim Img As String = “(?<!([E][+-][0-9]+))([-]?\d+\.?\d*([E][+-][0-9]+)?" & _ 
 "(?![0-9.E])(?:i)|([-]?\d*\.?\d+)?([E][+-][0-9]+)?\s*(?:i)(?![0-9.E]))” 

 Dim Number As String = “((?<Real>(” & Real & “))|(?<Imag>(” & Img & “)))”
 Dim Re, Im As Double
 Re = 0
 Im = 0

  For Each Match As Match In Regex.Matches(input, Number)

      If Not Match.Groups(“Real”).Value = String.Empty Then
         Re = Double.Parse(Match.Groups(“Real”).Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
      End If

     If Not Match.Groups(“Imag”).Value = String.Empty Then
           If Match.Groups(“Imag”).Value.ToString.Replace(” “, “”) = “-i” Then
                  Im = Double.Parse(“-1″, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
           ElseIf Match.Groups(“Imag”).Value.ToString.Replace(” “, “”) = “i” Then
                  Im = Double.Parse(“1″, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
           Else
                  Im = Double.Parse(Match.Groups(“Imag”).Value.ToString.Replace(“i”, “”), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  End If
  End If
 Next

     Dim result As New Complex(Re, Im)
      Return result
     End Function
```