# c# split input of a string

Tags: c#, split

I've recently moved from c++ to c# in my classes and I have looked all over and haven't found much. I am having the following problem. I am supposed to be able to let the user add a complex number. For Example

-3.2 - 4.1i I want to split and store as (-3.2) - (4.1i)

I know I can split at the - sign, but there are some problems like

4 + 3.2i or even just a single number 3.2i.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a regular expression..

Comment: To @Default's comment on "base paring on presence of `i`: likely `4` is perfectly valid complex number for that assignment (need teacher's input here :) )

Comment: if there's always spaces between the numbers and operations you could try to parse it with the [Complex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type. (No space would mean one number)

Comment: You may want to look at http://regexlib.com/UserPatterns.aspx?authorid=4a2830db-f869-4497-867b-f87f4ac5d839 and get some ideas whether regular expressions will help.

Comment: Thanks @Default and everyone else, I think i'll try to parse until a space. However I could see a problem with -3.2-4.1i

Comment: @Derked well, then we are back to regular expressions. on top of my mind it would be something like `[0-9]?[.][0-9]?i?`

Comment: For @Default's suggestion on Complex - turns out `System.Numerics.Complex` does not have `Parse` of any kind - so useful to store, no use for parsing.

Comment: I deleted my answer because Complex does not have a parser.  [This is the same post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982923/how-should-i-get-complex-numbers-from-string)

Comment: And what about `1e-3+4.2e-2i` or other floating point numbers? Also what about `5i-1`. It seems you need a pretty robust expression parser here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By matching all the valid input with a regex it's a matter of assembling it after. The regex works by

- `[0-9]+` matching 0-n numbers
- `[.]?` matching 0 or 1 dot
- `[0-9]+` matching 0-n numbers
- `i?` matching 0 or 1 "i"
- `|` or
- `[+-*/]?` matching 0 or 1 of the operators +, -, * or /

.

```
public static void ParseComplex(string input)
{
    char[] operators = new[] { '+', '-', '*', '/' };

    Regex regex = new Regex("[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]+i?|[+-/*]?");
    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(input))
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Value))
            continue;

        if (operators.Contains(match.Value[0]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("operator {0}", match.Value[0]);
            continue;
        }

        if (match.Value.EndsWith("i"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("imaginary part {0}", match.Value);
            continue;

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("real part {0}", match.Value);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This still has pleanty of flaws and ways it can blow up, but in kinda works.

```
struct Complex
{
    float re, im;

    public static Complex Parse(string text)
    {
        text=text.Replace(" ", string.Empty); //trim spaces
        float re=0, im=0;
        int i_index=text.IndexOf('i');
        if(i_index>=0) //if no 'i' is present process as real only
        {
            text=text.Substring(0, i_index); //ignore all after i

            int i=0;
            //find start of digits
            while(i<text.Length&&(text[i]=='+'||text[i]=='-'))
            {
                i++;
            }
            //find end of digits
            while(i<text.Length&&(char.IsNumber(text, i)|| text.Substring(i).StartsWith(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator)))
            {
                i++;
            }
            // parse real (first) portion
            float.TryParse(text.Substring(0, i), out re);
            // had 'i' but no numbers
            if(text.Length==0)
            {
                im=1;
            }
            else
            {
                //parse remaining value as imaginary
                text=text.Substring(i+1);
                float.TryParse(text, out im);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            float.TryParse(text, out re);
        }
        // Build complex number
        return new Complex() { re=re, im=im };
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("({0},{1})", re, im);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test=new[] { "1", "i", "5+2i", "-5+2i", "+5-2i", "0.23+0.72i" };

        for(int i=0; i<test.Length; i++)
        {
            Debug.Print( Complex.Parse(test[i]).ToString() );
        }
    }
}
```

resut:

```
(1,0)
(0,1)
(5,2)
(-5,2)
(5,2)
(0.23,0.72)
```